# Static email SMTP sender - is it correct? Should I dispose anything?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, smtp

I'm using an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. And I call this method in different controllers, but not using dependency injection.

When I publish my application on server, sometimes an exception is thrown. In my local machine, it works.

Should I dispose anything? Is it correct using like this?

PS: My GMAIL is authorized to send multiple emails (company email), the option of secure apps is enabled...

The exception message:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at at System.Net.Mail.SendMailAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendMailCallback(IAsyncResult result)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at..

Code:

```
public class EmailServices
{
    public static async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
    {
        MailMessage mensagemEmail = new MailMessage("myemail@gmail.com", email, subject, htmlMessage);
        mensagemEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        using (var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
        {
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword");
                client.Credentials = cred;
                await client.SendMailAsync(mensagemEmail);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should dispose all disposable things you create.

Comment: But it's not a disposable class, right? What should I do, in this case?

Comment: Do you know what `using` does?

Comment: Either way - `Dispose` or lack thereof is likely not related to the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: @mjwills I know. It automatically disposes. But I had this question. @ I get it. thanks.